# Problems with removing empty lines in nested lists (JasperReports)

Tags: xpath, jasper-reports, datasource

I want to create a report that lists order item data from an xml data source. For each item, I want to display the item's name, type and ID. The order items have a tree structure, meaning that there are root items and that some root items may have children (and child items might have children, etc.). Because the order items have a tree structure, I have chosen to create this report using lists and nested lists in the report in order to maintain the tree structure. In other words, if an item might have a child, I have created a nested list for that child within the bounds of the list of the [parent] item. The list rows should be removed if there are no rows found for the given list according to the query in the data set. The problem that I am having is that white space is sometimes showing when there are no rows for the nested lists.

Here is the example XML data:

```
<xml>
  <order>
    <items>
        <itemId>1</itemId>
        <itemType>G</itemType>
        <name>G1</name>
        <children>
            <childType>typeSV</childType>
            <items>
                <itemId>2</itemId>
                <name>SV1</name>
                <children>
                    <childType>typeCWI</childType>
                </children>
            </items>
        </children>
        <children>
            <childType>typeIAR</childType>
            <items>
                <itemId>3</itemId>
                <name>IAR1</name>
            </items>
        </children>
    </items>
    <items>
        <itemId>4</itemId>
        <itemType>G</itemType>
        <name>G2</name>
        <children>
            <childType>typeSV</childType>
            <items>
                <itemId>5</itemId>
                <name>SV2</name>
                <children>
                    <childType>typeCWI</childType>
                    <items>
                        <itemId>6</itemId>
                        <name>CWI</name>
                        <children>
                            <childType>typeUWSAT</childType>
                            <items>
                                <itemId>7</itemId>
                                <name>UWSAT</name>
                            </items>
                        </children>
                    </items>
                </children>
            </items>
        </children>
    </items>
    <items>
        <itemId>8</itemId>
        <itemType>G</itemType>
        <name>G3</name>
        <children>
            <childType>typeSV</childType>
            <items>
                <itemId>9</itemId>
                <name>SV3</name>
                <children>
                    <childType>typeCWI</childType>
                </children>
            </items>
        </children>
    </items>
    <items>
        <itemId>10</itemId>
        <itemType>G</itemType>
        <name>G4</name>
        <children>
            <childType>typeSV</childType>
        </children>
    </items>
    <items>
        <itemId>11</itemId>
        <itemType>AD</itemType>
        <name>AD1</name>
        <children>
            <childType>typeCP</childType>
            <items>
                <itemId>12</itemId>
                <name>CP1</name>
                <children>
                    <childType>typeAC</childType>
                </children>
            </items>
        </children>
    </items>
</order></xml>
```

The JRXML:

```
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="TestXml" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" isIgnorePagination="true" uuid="29a85d17-1c73-426a-a943-abd1a79d4d69">
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="TextXml"/>
<subDataset name="OrderItems" uuid="afd926ee-2c1e-4872-94e5-c3827d6ee20e">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="TextXml"/>
    <queryString language="xPath">
        <![CDATA[//items]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="itemId" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription>
            <![CDATA[itemId]]>
        </fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription>
            <![CDATA[name]]>
        </fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="itemType" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription>
            <![CDATA[itemType]]>
        </fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="childType" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription>
            <![CDATA[../childType]]>
        </fieldDescription>
    </field>
</subDataset>
<queryString language="xPath">
    <![CDATA[/xml]]>
</queryString>
<background>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</background>
<detail>
    <band height="120" splitType="Stretch">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
        <frame>
            <reportElement stretchType="ContainerBottom" x="0" y="0" width="560" height="120" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="cd28978a-d108-4dbf-bbdd-e4246bfb3034"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="ContainerBottom" x="0" y="0" width="560" height="120" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="56683f9b-46b2-432c-bc9d-325c6c4aceed">
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.headertoolbar.table.name" value="G"/>
                </reportElement>
                <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="OrderItems" uuid="5ad748aa-acb5-47eb-96e2-d62692015afc">
                        <dataSourceExpression>
                            <![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).dataSource("/xml/order/items[itemType='G']")]]>
                        </dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:listContents height="120" width="560">
                        <frame>
                            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="ContainerBottom" x="0" y="0" width="560" height="30" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="98750caa-ff8c-40da-bddd-57ef7d2db52f"/>
                            <box>
                                <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="ContainerBottom" mode="Opaque" x="360" y="0" width="100" height="30" backcolor="#A1A1A1" uuid="d58577b5-f861-496a-877e-c2a288b79d18"/>
                                <box>
                                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                </box>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
                                <textFieldExpression>
                                    <![CDATA[$F{itemType}]]>
                                </textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="ContainerBottom" mode="Opaque" x="460" y="0" width="100" height="30" backcolor="#A1A1A1" uuid="672a536b-199a-4ee3-a363-30e3b255d7f6"/>
                                <box>
                                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                </box>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
                                <textFieldExpression>
                                    <![CDATA[$F{itemId}]]>
                                </textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="ContainerBottom" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="359" height="30" backcolor="#A1A1A1" uuid="1670ab91-d0bb-43a1-9898-d8bb9cdaaec8"/>
                                <box>
                                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                                </box>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
                                <textFieldExpression>
                                    <![CDATA[$F{name}]]>
                                </textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </frame>
                        <frame>
                            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="ContainerBottom" x="0" y="30" width="560" height="90" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="b658a693-c1f5-45d8-8cd7-73bc8e77c76e">
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                            </reportElement>
                            <frame>
                                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="ContainerBottom" x="0" y="0" width="560" height="30" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="1f113e02-72f0-4b03-86e1-71a7341837fa"/>
                                <box>
                                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                </box>
                                <componentElement>
                                    <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="ContainerBottom" x="0" y="0" width="560" height="30" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="67539ab7-8fbe-45ce-9cbf-4f966415a2ef">
                                        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.headertoolbar.table.name" value="IAR"/>
                                    </reportElement>
                                    <jr:list printOrder="Vertical">
                                        <datasetRun subDataset="OrderItems" uuid="1a39b86b-eb8b-4fea-a2f4-d8278390b099">
                                            <dataSourceExpression>
                                                <![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).dataSource("/xml/order/items[itemId='"+$F{itemId}+"']/children[childType='typeIAR']/items")]]>
                                            </dataSourceExpression>
                                        </datasetRun>
                                        <jr:listContents height="30" width="560">
                                            <frame>
                                                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="560" height="30" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="bc9e2c9e-bca3-46ba-87aa-5bceb222bda0"/>
                                                <box>
                                                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                                </box>
                                                <textField>
                                                    <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="ContainerBottom" x="460" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="e31e95dc-714f-4f89-85b0-cb2927d3c0a4">
                                                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                                                    </reportElement>
                                                    <box>
                                                        <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                                        <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                                        <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                                    </box>
                                                    <textFieldExpression>
                                                        <![CDATA[$F{itemId}]]>
                                                    </textFieldExpression>
                                                </textField>
                                                <textField>
                                                    <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="ContainerBottom" x="30" y="0" width="330" height="30" uuid="526c14ee-a12e-4156-b130-a7d667136fc2">
                                                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                                                    </reportElement>
                                                    <box>
                                                        <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                                        <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                                    </box>
                                                    <textFieldExpression>
                                                        <![CDATA[$F{name}]]>
                                                    </textFieldExpression>
                                                </textField>
                                                <textField>
                                                    <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="ContainerBottom" x="360" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="33e53141-5aca-4ec5-af78-edf1c930d7c4">
                                                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                                                    </reportElement>
                                                    <box>
                                                        <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                                        <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                                        <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                                    </box>
                                                    <textFieldExpression>
                                                        <![CDATA[$F{childType}]]>
                                                    </textFieldExpression>
                                                </textField>
                                            </frame>
                                        </jr:listContents>
                                    </jr:list>
                                </componentElement>
                            </frame>
                            <frame>
                                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="ContainerBottom" x="0" y="30" width="560" height="60" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="38ba008a-05ee-4c35-9d36-c0b3e8fc36ea">
                                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                                </reportElement>
                                <componentElement>
                                    <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="ContainerBottom" x="0" y="0" width="560" height="60" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="613fc942-f6b3-449b-836d-58d469bbbc53">
                                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                                        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.headertoolbar.table.name" value="SV"/>
                                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                                    </reportElement>
                                    <jr:list printOrder="Vertical">
                                        <datasetRun subDataset="OrderItems" uuid="992b798d-0ad5-4c5b-b245-1a40d055b7f5">
                                            <dataSourceExpression>
                                                <![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).dataSource("/xml/order/items[itemId='"+$F{itemId}+"']/children[childType='typeSV']/items")]]>
                                            </dataSourceExpression>
                                        </datasetRun>
                                        <jr:listContents height="60" width="560">
                                            <frame>
                                                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="560" height="30" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="f063936c-ab95-465d-9501-0ed8e5d4dacc"/>
                                                <box>
                                                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                                </box>
                                                <textField>
                                                    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="460" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="4c7e80d3-6bc4-4281-8c7f-2ba6ba18fa74">
                                                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                                                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                                                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                                                    </reportElement>
                                                    <box>
                                                        <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                                        <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                                        <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                                    </box>
                                                    <textFieldExpression>
                                                        <![CDATA[$F{itemId}]]>
                                                    </textFieldExpression>
                                                </textField>
                                                <textField>
                                                    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="30" y="0" width="330" height="30" uuid="96042aa9-402a-4a8f-b008-b3d0ff94becd">
                                                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                                                    </reportElement>
                                                    <box>
                                                        <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                                        <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                                    </box>
                                                    <textFieldExpression>
                                                        <![CDATA[$F{name}]]>
                                                    </textFieldExpression>
                                                </textField>
                                                <textField>
                                                    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="360" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="2d3b1a7b-4bfb-4c12-bdaa-741af76a52fd">
                                                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                                                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                                                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                                                    </reportElement>
                                                    <box>
                                                        <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                                        <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                                        <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                                    </box>
                                                    <textFieldExpression>
                                                        <![CDATA[$F{childType}]]>
                                                    </textFieldExpression>
                                                </textField>
                                            </frame>
                                            <frame>
                                                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="ContainerBottom" x="0" y="30" width="560" height="30" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="77c3cf69-01ec-41c0-86e0-9b81d17c6a75">
                                                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                                                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                                                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                                                </reportElement>
                                                <componentElement>
                                                    <reportElement key="" positionType="Float" stretchType="ContainerBottom" x="0" y="0" width="560" height="30" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="4bec04d5-cd1f-4236-8867-aeba9579161a">
                                                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                                                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                                                        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.headertoolbar.table.name" value="CWI"/>
                                                    </reportElement>
                                                    <jr:list printOrder="Vertical">
                                                        <datasetRun subDataset="OrderItems" uuid="7517e1b5-fef5-4466-acdb-c83b082bbc1a">
                                                            <dataSourceExpression>
                                                                <![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).dataSource("/xml/order/items/children/items[itemId='"+$F{itemId}+"']/children[childType='typeCWI']/items")]]>
                                                            </dataSourceExpression>
                                                        </datasetRun>
                                                        <jr:listContents height="30" width="560">
                                                            <frame>
                                                                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="ContainerBottom" x="0" y="0" width="560" height="30" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="9fcf1658-09b4-4d40-983b-7934d6c44e43"/>
                                                                <box>
                                                                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                                                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                                                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                                                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                                                </box>
                                                                <textField>
                                                                    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="460" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="c51d6125-185c-4733-bcf2-a9828229b091">
                                                                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                                                                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                                                                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                                                                    </reportElement>
                                                                    <box>
                                                                        <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                                                        <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                                                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                                                        <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                                                    </box>
                                                                    <textFieldExpression>
                                                                        <![CDATA[$F{itemId}]]>
                                                                    </textFieldExpression>
                                                                </textField>
                                                                <textField>
                                                                    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="60" y="0" width="300" height="30" uuid="5f06b7e6-7d49-4dee-832f-a5a35285a5a6">
                                                                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                                                                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                                                                    </reportElement>
                                                                    <box>
                                                                        <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                                                        <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                                                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                                                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                                                    </box>
                                                                    <textFieldExpression>
                                                                        <![CDATA[$F{name}]]>
                                                                    </textFieldExpression>
                                                                </textField>
                                                                <textField>
                                                                    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="360" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="259ab20e-a5e5-4fa1-ad8a-4cc602e57ad0">
                                                                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                                                                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                                                                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                                                                    </reportElement>
                                                                    <box>
                                                                        <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                                                        <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                                                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                                                        <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                                                                    </box>
                                                                    <textFieldExpression>
                                                                        <![CDATA[$F{childType}]]>
                                                                    </textFieldExpression>
                                                                </textField>
                                                            </frame>
                                                        </jr:listContents>
                                                    </jr:list>
                                                </componentElement>
                                            </frame>
                                        </jr:listContents>
                                    </jr:list>
                                </componentElement>
                            </frame>
                        </frame>
                    </jr:listContents>
                </jr:list>
            </componentElement>
        </frame>
    </band>
</detail>
```

Below I've exported this report to .xls format and taken screenshots in order to illustrate the actual result that I am experiencing now and the desired result.

**Screenshot of Actual Result in XLS Format (with red lines surrounding the unwanted white space):**
[image: Actual result (with red lines surrounding the unwanted white space)]

**Screenshot of Desired Result in XLS Format:**
[image]

It seems that the empty rows are removed as I would expect when the nested list for IAR items has no rows (using the "Remove Line When Blank" option") or when there are neither IAR- nor SV-type rows for their respective nested lists. However, when the list for SV-type items is non-empty and the CWI-type items is empty, white space shows where CWI-type rows would be located. I have tried removing the unwanted white space by floating all of the report components (e.g. text fields, lists, frames, etc.), setting the stretch type of all report components to "ElementGroupBottom" and "ContainerBottom", but to no avail.

Does anyone know how I can make this report in order to achieve the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to reduce the height of the List SV element to 30, while leaving its cell height to 60.  That way the cell height will remain 30 when there's no data in List CWI, but will stretch to 60 or more when List CWI produces rows.

The disadvantage is that List CWI will be obscured in Jaspersoft Sudio's design view, you'd only be able to see it by drilling down to List SV.

The changes would be the following:

- leave List SV cell height to 60
- change List SV element height from 60 to 30 (note that at this step Studio might automatically change the cell height to 30, if it does that set it back to 60)
- change the height of the frame in which List SV is placed from 60 to 30
- change the height of the parent frame from 90 to 60
- change the element and cell height of List G from 120 to 90
- change the height of the detail band and of the top level frame from 120 to 90